# Which star to send a Colony ship

Tags: planets

Assuming our current knowledge of exoplanets which star would you send a colony ship. Assume you a maximum range of 40 light-years.

Earth is no longer habitable so the ship is simply playing the numbers and cant do any further research or send a mission ahead they are simply heading for the most probable.

Comment: Traveling to another star is nowhere near as practical as simply setting up orbital platforms to live on.  If you can do the travel, you can much more easily do the orbital stations.  And you can research as much as you like from large orbitals.

Comment: Following from @StephenG: why not just head to Proxima Centauri and regroup from there?

Comment: @nzaman My only issues with this is that you're doing the planning second (always bad) and improvising (worse), while at the same time you're leaving a resource base you have in-depth knowledge and mapping of (the Solar system) for one you don't, which is exploring blind.

Comment: I'd go with orbital platforms too. Trying to find the most suitable planet with the actual knowledge would be like an European during the 15th century trying to find out where the best spot is to found a colony between Greenland and Eastern America with almost no knowledge of these places except that they exist. It's pretty much a suicide considering how complicated space travel is.

Comment: You have [ten to choose from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_potentially_habitable_exoplanets).  I required less than 30 seconds on Google to find the linked list.  Voting to close for insufficient research.

Comment: @JBH I didn't think that we could close for that. Insufficient research is mentioned in the reasons to downvote not close vote.

Comment: @Bellerophon, that's a good point.  I'll change my vote.

Answer (score 3):

A quick hunt online yields you several candidates, but you can't really beat Proxima Centauri b.

If our colony ship is our last ditch effort then you would not want a mission to go on any longer than it needs - anything could go wrong and adding centuries to a mission would drastically increase the risk of failure.

Proxima Centauri b is only just over 4 light years away, has a temperature of 234 Kelvin (not bad), radius the same as Earth (predicted), Mass only slightly larger at 1.3. The only thing odd is its period of 12 days - but if the boot fits it's the better choice.

All other options are 12 or more away - even at that next distance (to say Luyten b), at 5% speed of light, an astronomical speed, you're adding at least another 160 years to your journey - much longer and therefore much more risky.

Comment: What drive methods are you assuming to get the speeds you use to calculate your journey times?

Comment: How is 234K or about -39 °C (-38 °F) not bad. Because of this for me it would be the first one not to go to. You at least want liquid water somewhere on the planet.

Answer (score 3):

**Things To Consider**

The same tech to build a star-ship capable of reaching another star with any sort of appreciable cargo and passenger capacity means you can live pretty much any environment habitable. I'll detail a basic outline of what such a ship would be like with our current understanding of physics and what we currently know to be possible.

First, any star-ship traveling to another star is going to both be massive and designed to support a population for a very, very long time basically approaching indefinitely. It is going to have a massive power source, probably a very very large fusion reactor, or possibly use antimatter somehow. Next, it will need to be able to not only fabricate anything and everything the colonists will need from raw materials, but also be capable of self repair. Space isn't empty and at percentages of light speed dust particles and even atoms will be severely ablating your ship. This means its got to be huge, its got to be armored, and it has to have some way of repairing or replacing the massive armored prow. It has to also be capable of supporting life for vast periods of time, possibly tens of thousands of years BEFORE it is required to support the founding of a colony, which is itself a massive undertaking.

With this tech (fully automated manufacture, fusion energy, long term ecology and life support etc etc) you don't NEED another planet. Build the same vessel minus the giant engines and you have an arcology structure that can support life right here on the not so "unihabitable" Earth. Build a ton of them and place them in orbit even. Build em on Mars, build em on Titan, build em anywhere its convenient to build really. The Earth has such a monumentally gargantuan amount of resources that you could build thousands of kilometers long orbital platforms a year until the sun burned out and still not run out of material to build them with. That's excluding all of the resources in our own solar system. The issue Isn't how much resources we have, its a matter of possessing the energy to   harvest them.

The biggest limiting factor to how much we can gather is only limited by the cost and amount of available energy to do so and the manpower needed. If you have mature fusion technology and automated factories (a prerequisite to build any sizable star ship under current physics) you now have basically unlimited access to resources at very very little cost. The same tech to build a ship that can reach another star and establish a practically sized colony means that pretty much anywhere you can get hydrogen and access to raw materials is now habitable. The amount of resources locked up in just our solar system are so huge that we could literally never leave our solar system until the sun dies and STILL have never harvested or used even 1% of them. If we were to seriously begin building orbital habitats and colonizing the asteroid belt and other planets our solar system could support trillions of people more or less indefinitely.

In those terms why even bother leaving home? Perhaps in the spirit of exploration or possibly even just because we could. Point being, In current level understanding of science and physics we could exist indefinitely within our own solar system for as long as there is a sun at the middle of it. That isn't to say we wouldn't try colonizing another planet (and its moons, asteroids, and the rest of it's solar system). I'm just saying that its about another 5 billion years or so until we would even need to start thinking about doing so out of actual necessity. In an odd catch-22 The tech to leave our solar system renders the necessity of having to do so an obsolete notion. If we did have to it pretty much wouldn't matter where we went, so long as its got metals and hydrogen.

Comment: There is a possibility that you're leaving not for a natural calamity - but a human-made one. Perhaps for instance someone made an AI that seeks and destroys all traces of civilisation in the solar system. Or Earth has been turned into nano-jelly. Or a political situation escalates such that you need to escape.

Comment: Which is why I pointed out that what planet you choose is largely irrelevant. Anywhere with hydrogen and metals will do. The tech to build a ship capable of the mission renders habitability of wherever you go irrelevant. You just need to be able to build more habitats when you get there.